# 404 Laravel 8 хотя есть шаблон, маршрут, контроллер

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, laravel-8, error404

Не работает URL 127.0.0.1/user/<тут айди пользователя> и 127.0.0.1/category/<тут категория>. Также не работает страница добавления статьи. Файл web.php:

https://pastebin.com/WFWwLjV6

Файл ArticlesController.php:

https://pastebin.com/w2hEyvMu

Хотя шаблоны есть:

https://ibb.co/L6qQbH4

Скриншоты:

https://ibb.co/VgFjWFc

https://ibb.co/1b8w2LQ

https://ibb.co/w7rQRnB

Что не так? Помогите пожалуйста. И почему одни маршруты работают, а другие нет? Ведь всё есть.

после того как я закамментировал эту строку:

```
Route::get('/{article}/{id}', [ArticlesController::class, 'detail'])->name('detail');
```

страница просмотра пользователя стала работать, страница добавления статьи тоже стала работать, страница просмотра рубрики тоже стала работать

Comment: я уже чистил кэш командой `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё я разобрался. Мне помог пользователь Kirill_ с дискорд-сервера LaravelRUS он написал:

посмотри как ты написал ссылку /{article}/{id}, элемент {article} не как строка а как переменная, и она перехватывает все ссылки что дальше делая их нерабочими

Всё дело было в элементе {article} который принимал урл и перенаправлял запрос на свой контроллер, а не на нужный контроллер для этого url.